# Why can any quadratic equation be reduced to the product of its two factors involving the roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I'm studying algebra and I'd like to know why can any quadratic equation be reduced to the product of its two factors.

And why $(x-α) (x-β)$ where $α$ and $β$ are its two roots?

And why is the sum of roots i.e. $α+β=-b/a$ and product of roots $\, αβ = c/a$?

Comment: See [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), for the quadratic example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let an arbitrary quadratic expression be:
$$q(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$
Define
$$\alpha=\frac1{2a} (-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac})$$
$$\beta=\frac1{2a} (-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac})$$
Then a little algebra shows that
$$\alpha+\beta = -\frac{b}{a}$$
$$\alpha \beta = \frac{c}{a}$$
$$a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=ax^2-a(\alpha+\beta)x + a\alpha \beta = ax^2+bx+c$$

You should now be able to see the answer to all of your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a derivation of this factorization using completing the square on its quadratic formula page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula#Method_3 It may also be enlightening to add and multiply the results of the quadratic formula:

$$\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} + \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} = \frac{-2b}{2a}$$

And:

$$\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \cdot \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} = \frac{(-b)^2-(\sqrt{b^2-4ac})^2}{2a} = \frac{b^2-(b^2-4ac)}{4a^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Without using quadratic formula, we can do as follows.

**Tool:** If, $a≠0$ and $\alpha, \beta$ are the roots of $ax^2+bx+c$ then,

$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$$

---

We have,

$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$$

$$\begin{align} ax^2+bx+c=&ax^2-a(\alpha+\beta)x+a\alpha\beta&\end{align}$$

$$b=-a(\alpha+\beta) ~ ,c=a\alpha\beta$$

$$\alpha+\beta=...~ \alpha\beta=...$$

I leave the rest of the last line to you.